# Label sticking next to another label

Tags: html, css, forms

I am having a simple registration form, but one of the label fields sticks next to another label field.

Currently it looks like this: 
[image]

Email should be under the Username, not next to it. Other form elements align nicely, but not these two.

```css
label {
  float: left;
}

input {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="user-name">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name" required>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="user-email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="user-email" name="user-email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and added </div></div> for you

Comment: Why not use fieldset?

Comment: Try this 

Give the labels display: inline-block;
Give them a fixed width
Align text to the right
That is:

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}​

Comment: it went below when i removed your css.

Comment: Try adding a `<br />` after the username. That should make it into a new line.

Comment: @Darius, sorry to say, I don't think the answer you choose is right because if you view the page in bigger screen it moves both the controls in opposite direction, I guess which is not anyone needs. May be that is what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going with `float` you have to know about using `clear` property for it's next elements. So a best way to handle is, to create a `after` pseudo-element on the parent and `clear:both`.

In the below code have added 'field' class for each container and styled it with `:after`.

```css
.field::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  float: left;
}

input {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="user-name">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label for="user-email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="user-email" name="user-email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not against your answer! but you can optimize the code and using `float` is very old and this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `flex`, clean and less code.

```css
.form-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.username,
.useremail {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="username">
      <label for="user-name">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="useremail">
      <label for="user-email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="user-email" name="user-email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Labels and input fields are stacked from the left and the right, resp., due to the css `float` properties. Note that the label/input pairs render on individual lines when removing the css, though without proper vertical alignment.

The CSS `display: table` property and friends can be employed to rectify this. Basically they cause the renderer to apply table layouting to elements other than `table`and descendants.

```css
.d-t {
  display: table;
}

.d-tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.d-tr > label, .d-tr > input {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="d-t">
    <div class="d-tr">
      <label for="user-name">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="d-tr">
      <label for="user-email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="user-email" name="user-email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```